# simplest way to send an object with Tcpclinet c#

Tags: c#, .net, tcpclient

im new to c# and i was wondering , what is the simplest way to send an object using tcpClient , itried the following code but it throws a wierd error 
client code :

```
TcpClient client = new TcpClient(ip, port);
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream());
NetworkStream strm = client.GetStream();
BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
Transaction tx = new transaction();

string msg = string.Empty;

msg = "transaction";
writer.WriteLine(msg);
writer.Flush();

formatter.Serialize(strm,tx);
```

and on the receiving end

Server Code :

```
while(true){
TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
NetworkStream strm = client.GetStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(client.GetStream());
string msg = string.Empty;
while (!((msg = reader.ReadLine()).Equals("exit"))){

Transaction tx = (Transaction)formatter.Deserialize(strm);

}
```

it produces this error on the server

```
input stream is not a valid ibinary format intital content is :0c-02-00-00 .....
```

so can someone please help me or if there another simple and clean way of sending objects using tcpclient ?

Comment: It seems odd to me that this doesn't work, however: **please please please** don't use `BinaryFormatter`... ever. It is *going* to cause problems. Question, though; are you only sending one payload? or a stream of payloads? (it actually matters, a bit) i.e. will you send one object and then close the socket? or are you trying to have an ongoing conversation with multiple objects (frames)?

Comment: Do you need a [TCP Listener](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcplistener?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8)?

Comment: yes i need a tcp listner and if icant use binaryFormatter what should i use then , and its only one client and one server ,also im sending only one payload which is that transaction object ,i will update the question to reveal the full code

Comment: ah, the edit shows the problem; give me a sec

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The underlying problem here is tied into the way that you are mixing two different mechanisms to read and write to a stream, specifically: using `StreamReader` *and* a separate stream-based parser. It is *also* a bad idea to do this with `StreamWriter`, but ... I think you would get away with it sort-of, although it is still a bad idea.

The *problem* here is that `StreamReader` is *greedy*. When you ask it for a line, it doesn't read from the stream byte-by-byte looking for a `\r` or `\n` - it grabs a *buffer* of data from the stream, and then processes it *as you ask for it*. In this way, it assumes that it is now the **sole owner** of the stream.

So; when you do this:

```cs
while (!((msg = reader.ReadLine()).Equals("exit"))){
   Transaction tx = (Transaction)formatter.Deserialize(strm);
}
```

the reader consumes *more than* just `"transaction\r\n`" - it consumes that line *and some undefined number of bytes from whatever comes after*. Then, when `BinaryFormatter` tries to read the stream, it finds itself half way through a message, and it explodes in a shower of sparks.

Ideally, limit yourself to *one serialization mechanism*. Meaning: lose  `StreamReader`/`StreamWriter` **completely** here.

If I could propose an alternative mechanism using protobuf-net and inheritance:

```cs
[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(1, typeof(ShutdownMessage))]
[ProtoInclude(2, typeof(TransactionMessage))]
public abstract class MessageBase {} 

[ProtoContract]
public sealed class ShutdownMessage : MessageBase {}

[ProtoContract]
public sealed class TransactionMessage : MessageBase {
    // your data here
}
```

and now you can *send* any number of messages with:

```cs
public void Send(MessageBase message) {
    Serializer.SerializeWithLengthPrefix(strm, message, PrefixStyle.Base128);
}
```

and *receive* any number of messages with:

```cs
while (true) {
    var msg = Serializer.DeserializeWithLengthPrefix<MessageBase>(strm, PrefixStyle.Base128);
    if (msg is null || msg is ShutdownMessage) break; // all done
    switch (msg)
    {
        case TransactionMessage tx: ProcessTransaction(tx); break;
        // etc
    }
}
```

Comment: okey i will try using protobuf instead , and thank you so much sir for your time , you are my hero

Comment: @Ezio just keep in mind: the *real problem here* was the combination of `StreamReader` with ... anything else; once you get around that bit, *any* serializer should work, for differing values of "work"

Comment: i tried to do as you say but this time it seems that the problem is in desirialization , in my transaction class i have another object called "Output" ,and when ideszerialize it shows me this error message : no parameterless constructor found for myproject.Output , please help !!

Comment: _no parameterless constructor found for myproject.Output_ Well, do you have one? If not you need to add one!

Comment: @Ezio bear in mind I can't see that your from here! However: there is a SkipConstructor flag you can enable on ProtoContractAttribute if it helps

Answer (score 1):

There are a *lot* of reasons not to use `BinaryFormatter`. **If this was me** (and I'm biased in this), I would switch to something like protobuf-net, which doesn't have the same concerns as `BinaryFormatter`, but: it does require some tweaks to your types - usually annotating them with some attributes to help the library, for example:

```cs
public class Transaction {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

might become

```cs
[ProtoContract]
public class Transaction {
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public int Id {get;set;}
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

After that, the code *should* be simply:

```cs
Serializer.Serialize(strm, tx); // this is ProtoBuf.Serializer
// and now close the "send" pipe; fine to leave the "receive" pipe, though
```

and

```cs
Serializer.Deserialize<Transaction>(strm); // again, ProtoBuf.Serializer
```

However! There's something slightly odd in play, as *as far as I can see*, the code shown in the question should work, unless something odd is happening.

---

Note: if you are sending *multiple* payloads (i.e. you need to partition it into frames), or if you don't want to have to worry about closing the send pipe, then:

```cs
Serializer.SerializeWithLengthPrefix(strm, tx, PrefixStyle.Base128);
```

and

```cs
Serializer.DeserializeWithLengthPrefix<Transaction>(strm, PrefixStyle.Base128);
```

Comment: @Ezio this won't fix the fundamental issue here - give me 2 minutes to finish a second answer explaining why (from your edit); however, I'd say it is still a good idea!

Comment: is it mandatory to add [ProtoMember(x)] for all members , or is it optionnal

Comment: is it mandatory to add [ProtoMember(x)] for all members , or is it optionnal

Comment: @Ezio protobuf needs hints to understand how to encode the data, which is what we're doing here (basically: it doesn't send names, so it needs a way to reliably map numbers to fields); you *can* also use `[DataContract]` / `[DataMember(1)]` instead of protobuf-net's own attributes, but that gives you less control. However! Any serializer should be fine; if you don't want to use protobuf-net, that OK - even `BinaryFormatter` should work (but: please don't!) *if you can stop doing the `StreamReader`/`StreamWriter` thing* - that is the actual problem here (see other answer)